# Why does MVC 4 dispose the controller when action await something?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

Why is my controller being disposed after the `await` statement?

```
    public async Task<ViewResult> MyAction()
    {
            await Task.Yield();

            // controller disposed at this point... why?

            return this.View();
    }
```

My controller uses resources that it disposes by overriding the `Dispose` method... but using async/await seems to break this, because it disposes the controller as soon as the await statement is executed... how can I dispose resources in a way that async/await is supported?

**EDIT:** Last methods in callstack of the dispose method:

```
MyWebRole.dll!MyWebRole.Code.MyController.Dispose(bool disposing = true) Line 102   C#
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Dispose() + 0x25 bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.ReleaseController(System.Web.Mvc.IController controller = {MyWebRole.Areas.App.Controllers.LongPollingController}) + 0x3e bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest.AnonymousMethod__5() + 0x70 bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.MakeVoidDelegate.AnonymousMethod__0() + 0x2d bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.BeginSynchronous<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.AnonymousMethod__7(System.IAsyncResult _ = {System.Web.Mvc.Async.SimpleAsyncResult}) + 0x2b bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.End() + 0x99 bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult = {System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>}, object tag = {object}) + 0x3c bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult = {System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>}, object tag = {object}) + 0x29 bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest.AnonymousMethod__d() + 0x27 bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.GetCallInAppTrustThunk.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Action f = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}) + 0x20 bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(System.Action action = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}) + 0x3e bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult = {System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>}) + 0x77 bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult result = {System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>}) + 0x27 bytes
```

The `Dispose` method is being called with `disposing = true`... thats bad. Maybe a bug?

**EDIT 2:** I have tryed subclassing `AsyncController` but the same happens.

Any work around?

Comment: Is a reference retained to the controller after the await statement?

Comment: Only the `this` itself... it is the same object before and after the `await`.

Comment: It is the same... but disposed.

Comment: Is another thread calling dispose on the object? Have you tried setting a break point on the dispose function and see who's calling it?

Comment: Edited question to include callstack of dispose method... it is MVC that calls it.

Comment: No, it does not. It is not needed in MVC 4. Microsoft documentation says it is provided only for compatibility with MVC 3. Unless that is not true. I'll try!

Comment: What!!! Where is the comment asking if I was subclassing AsyncController??? My previous comment was an answer to that.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, sorry about previous comment - removed as it was wrong (as you've noticed :) )

Comment: Ok... thanks for the hint anyway... I tried it for no avail. Controller is still being disposed. MVC 4 is crazy... it disposes something that will continue to be used later. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: Even if it is a bug, I'd be happy with a work around. Maybe another place to dispose my resources, instead of overriding the `Dispose` method.

Comment: Though of checking the `bool disposing` argument of the `Dispose` method, but is is `true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call stack shown in the question is from MVC3 and not MVC4. Unfortunately MVC3 does not support `Task`-based async calls. When you call await the task may very well be started but MVC3 doesn't know anything about that, so it just calls `ToString()` on it and returns it as a `ContentResult`.

The `Task`-based async support was added in MVC4, and in fact doesn't even require deriving from `AsyncController`. All `Controllers` in MVC4 support sync, and `Task`-based async. You only need `AsyncController` if you use the Async/Completed pattern.

Comment: Well... in fact I thought I was using MVC 4, but you are right it was MVC 3, maybe someone forgot to upgrade the project. Now it is working as it was expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 good eye. I haven't used either version of MVC a whole lot. What in the stack trace tells you that it is MVC3 and not 4?

Comment: @chuex The calls to SecurityUtil would not be present in MVC4.

Comment: @Eilon - thanks for the answer. I was wondering how any mere mortal could spot the difference based on the call stack. Then I looked at your profile and put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: @chuex I actually asked another developer on the team (the one who wrote this part of MVC), so the full credit goes to him! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace it appears that whatever started the process request decided it to end it, thus you lose the reference to the controller and it's eligible for garbage collection/disposing. I would look in to what started the process request and why it would be ending it.

Comment: Thats is not the case... it is MVC 4 that is disposing my controller on purpose, not the garbage collector, but I don't know why, since the action is `async`. Also, the code execution of the code continues normally after the `await`, and I can see that it is alive, but disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it troubled me for a full day. I finally realised the ActionInvoker I was hooking up in my ControllerFactory was inheriting from ControllerActionInvoker. When I changed that to AsyncControllerActionInvoker the problem went away.